# Can I copy the skew from one object to another?

Tags: inkscape, skew

I have two images which I want to skew with the same amount. Is there a way I could 'copy' the skew from one image to the other one? I could do this by eye but this would not be an ideal solution.

I want to go from this:

[image]

to this, but with the exact same amount of skew.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can skew numerically in the Transform panel. [see example](https://imgur.com/8Q85SJN). Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the 'Edit → XML Editor...', copy the `transform`-attribute and paste it on the other object. It works best when the original was only skewed and not scaled or rotated as well.

Select your object and copy the value of the attribute:

[image: Transform attribute highlighted on original object]

Select the second object, click the '+' in the top-left, enter `transform` for the attribute name and paste the value:

[image: Entering the attribute name on the second object]

You may have to adjust the position, but the skew should now be the same:

[image: Second object with the skew applied]

Alternatively, you can use the 'Object → Transform...' panel switched to the 'Matrix' tab.

Select your first object, check the 'Edit current matrix' box and write down the values in the six input boxes. Then select your second object, disable the 'Edit current matrix' setting, enter the six values and click apply.

[image: Matrix tab of the 'Transform' panel]

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Many thanks